# Calculating 3 textboxes in percentages using c#

Tags: c#, textbox, percentage

I'm trying to make a simple table where every columns (textboxes) has it own percentage, but i couldn't calculate the percentage

```
void Main()
{
    double column1 = 0.0;
    double column2 = 0.0;
    double column3 = 0.0;

    Console.WriteLine(
      ((column1 * 20) / 100).ToString(),column2 * 60)/ 100).ToString(),column3 * 20)/ 100).ToString())));
}
```

Comment: Which error keeps showing?

Comment: It's not totally an error, it's just doesn't calculate

Comment: What do you mean "every columns (textboxes) has its own percentage?"
Do you mean the relative width of the columb? if so - why are you assigning values to `textBox4.Text`? 
Also - your use of brackets and commas are really unclear... please make sure it is right and not a typing error.

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv textbox4,Text is used to show the result for the 3 textboxes..

Comment: @Lan What results? You question is very unclear - Please update it. Do you want to show text  divided by commas that each one of it has a number calculated from the value of each one of the TextBoxes?

Comment: It's clear that you have a problem with parentheses. Try this one: `textBox4.Text = ((column1 * 20)/100).ToString() + ", " + ((column2 * 60)/100).ToString() + ", " + ((column3 * 20)/100).ToString();`

Comment: I don't get it, your variables column1,2,3  are equal to zero so there is no sense of calculating the percentage.

Comment: Maybe this is just an example saying that there's an "error". it's pretty unclear what's the problem there. But as I stated, there's a clear error in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some parentheses `()`, the comma sign must be a string `","` and you have to concatenate strings by using the `+` sing:

```
textBox4.Text = (column1 * 20 / 100).ToString() + "," + (column2 * 60 / 100).ToString() + "," + (column3 * 20 / 100).ToString();
```

In the comments you said that you have 3 textboxes and textbox4 is used to show the result for the 3 textboxes therefore I think you want something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double column1 = 0; 
    double column2 = 0;
    double column3 = 0;

    double.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out column1);
    double.TryParse(textBox2.Text,out column2);
    double.TryParse(textBox3.Text,out column3);

    string[] results = {((column1 * 20)/100).ToString(), 
                        ((column2 * 60)/100).ToString(),
                        ((column3 * 20)/100).ToString()} ;

    textBox4.Text = string.Join(",",results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to this,

```
textBox4.Text = column1 * 20 / 100 + " ," + column2 * 60 / 100 + ", " + column3 * 20 / 100;
```

I'm not sure that this will solve your entire problem, but it atleast will get your code building. I removed all the unnecessary brackets.

Note that you will get 0's as you are declaring your column variables to have the value of 0 on each click of that button.

Comment: * Remember, when assigning a value to a variable, that expression must comply with the type. i.e. if the variable on LHS is a string, the output (RHS) must also be a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have comma separated calculated values in one text box, then please try this:

```
textBox4.Text = $"{(column1 * 20) / 100}, {(column2 * 60) / 100}, {(column3 * 20) / 100}";
```

If you need to have calculated values each in own textbox, then you need to have three textboxes, but not one

```
textBox4.Text = ((column1 * 20) / 100).ToString();
textBox5.Text = ((column2 * 60) / 100).ToString();
textBox6.Text = ((column3 * 20) / 100).ToString();
```